# TTS in Flutter. My device does not produce the sound

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, text-to-speech

Can you check why this flutter code does not pronounce the word I want it to pronounce in chinese. I used the latest version of TTS in pub dev which is 3.70 and downloaded it in pubsec.yalm and I am using a Pixel 3A API34 as my emulator and I verified that the sound is to the max, here is my code：

```
import 'package:flutter_tts/flutter_tts.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:test2/notifiers/flashcards_notifiers.dart';

class TTSButton extends StatefulWidget {
  const TTSButton({super.key});

  @override
  State<TTSButton> createState() => _TTSButtonState();
}

class _TTSButtonState extends State<TTSButton> {

  bool _isTapped = false;

  FlutterTts _tts= FlutterTts();

  @override
  void initState() {
    _setUpTts();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _tts.stop();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Consumer<FlashcardsNotifier>(
      builder: (_, notifier,__) => 
       IconButton(onPressed: (){
          _runTts(text: notifier.word1.character);
          _isTapped = true;
          setState(() {});
            Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 5000),(){
              _isTapped = false;
              setState(() {  
              });
            });
      }, icon: Icon(Icons.audiotrack, size:50, color: _isTapped ? Colors.amber : Color.fromARGB(255, 11, 11, 11))),
    );
  }



  _setUpTts() async {
    await _tts.setLanguage('zh-Cn');
    await _tts.setSpeechRate(0.40);
  }

  _runTts({required String text}) async {
    await _tts.speak(text);
  }
}
```

I hope someone can help me solve this issue.